# Multiplicity constraint violation debug

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm getting a multiplicity constraint violation in my entity model.

On my entity model I have two relationship properties:

1. SubstanceTypeMixConstituents
2. Category

SubstanceTypeMixConstituents
 - Multiplicity * (Many)
Category
 - Multiplicity: 1 (One)
 - Foreign key, not null

[image]

How do I find what causing the problem and resolve this issue?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference expected at least one related object, but the query returned no related objects from the data store.
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item)
   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubstanceType_BEE32ACA75386E981F7CA3F6A3C565BC1D8ADACA228C603A2EACC918DCDCBA30.get_Category()
```

Comment: @Michael - you lost me here: `I have a multiplicity constraint on one releationship of 1 (One) where the database has a foreign key that are not null and a second relationship of * (Many) where the database has a many to many relationship`. Do you have a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the post in order to make more sense. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Michael - a screenshot of your model would be best, but as far as I understand, you have two entities - `Category` and `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` which have a `One-to-many` relationship - a `Category` can have multiple `SubstanceTypeMixConstituents`, but a `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` can have (and **must** have) only one `Category` (correct me if I am wrong). The error message you get means exactly what it says - you are either trying to save a `Category` with an empty collection of `SubstanceTypeMixConstituents`, or a `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` without a `Category`.

Comment: @Yakimych: Put the part: `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` without `Category` as an answer because it will be the problem.

Comment: @Ladislav - How do you figure it's not the other way around though?

Comment: I have added a diagram. The exception occurs sometimes when requesting all SubstanceTypes.

Comment: @Michael - The "diagram" you added is rather confusing. Is it your model, or your database? Why are there 2 arrows from `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` to `SubstanceType` and back? Please, take a screenshot of your EDM in the designer and put it out here instead, so that we can see the fields and the navigation properties. Furthermore, `The exception occurs sometimes when requesting all SubstanceTypes` is just not good enough. You need to show the code you are executing and point out the line that throws the exception. Otherwise, it's just guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you have two entities - `Category` and `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` which have a `One-to-many` relationship - a `Category` can have multiple `SubstanceTypeMixConstituents`, but a `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` can have (and must have) only one `Category` (correct me if I am wrong). The error message you get means exactly what it says - you are either trying to save a `Category` with an empty collection of `SubstanceTypeMixConstituents`, or a `SubstanceTypeMixConstituent` without a `Category`.